# How to order records based on a sub-sample of association counts?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 3.2 say I have 3 models: Athlete, Event and Country

```
Class Athlete
  has_many :events
  has_many :countries, through: :event
end

Class Event
  belongs_to :athlete, counter_cache: true
  belongs_to :country, counter_cache: true
end

Class Country
  has_many :events
  has_many :Athletes, through: :event
end
```

So I can now easily generate an array of Athletes ordered by the number of Events they have participated in.

```
scope :ranked, :order => 'athletes.events_count DESC'
```

But what if I need an array of Athletes that have evented in a particular country, and ordered by their number of events **in that country**.

```
#country
def show
  @country.find(params[:id])
  @athletes_leaderboard = Athlete.includes(:events).where(id: @country.events.uniq.map(&:athlete_id)).ranked
end
```

gives me a unique list of Athletes that have evented in that country, but it is ranked by their **total** event count, not by their country event count.

How can I order by their country event count, while maintaining database performance.

Answer (score 0):

The query involves a bit joins with a subquery.

```
country_id = params[:id]
subsql = Event.select("events.athlete_id AS a_id, count(events.id) AS country_event_count").where("events.country_id = ?", country_id).group("a_id").to_sql
@athletes_leaderboard = Athlete.joins("JOIN (#{subsql}) AS participated_events ON participated_events.a_id = athletes.id").
  order("participated_events.country_event_count DESC")
```

The result of `@athletes_leaderboard` is not `ActiveRecord::Relation` anymore. It is database result rows. You will need to iterate through the results and render it in your views. For example (using HAML):

```
- @athletes_leaderboard.each do |athlete_data|
  = link_to athlete_data["name"], athlete_path(athlete_data["id"])
```

You might want to cache the leaderboard in an in-memory store (like Memcache) so that the database doesn't get hit often.

Comment: this looks promising, but I'm getting `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"` and I don't understand enough to be able to debug this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Let me try debugging again. Meanwhile, could you show the output of `puts @athletes_leaderboard.to_sql`?

Comment: I missed out `JOIN`. Could you try it again?

Comment: thanks catcyborg, this appears to be working, and I've learned something new! Can you help me understand a bit more? How would you modify this to accommodate a grandparent relationship? For example, `Continent has_many :countries`, and displaying the leaderboard for a continent. Thanks!